# embedding html in php error

Tags: php, html

I think I have a syntax error but I can't spot it, any ideas?

```
if($infozz['count'] <= $infozz['limit'])
{
mail($infozz['email'], "Your incident report copy!", $bodyz);

echo <<<EOT
<html>

<head>

<title> Summary Report </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment/style/style3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
Summary Report

</div>

<div class="mess"> 

Type of incident: {$infoz['type']}<br><br>

Date upon entry: {$infoz['date']}<br><br>

Time upon entry: {$infoz['time']}<br><br>

Your account name: {$infoz['reporter']}<br><br>

Your incident ID number: {$infoz['ID']}<br><br>

Your description of the incident: {$infoz['desc']}<br><br>

An email has been sent to your account<br>


</div>

</body>
</html>

EOT;

}
```

Comment: What is the syntax error message?

Comment: What error do you get that makes you think it's a syntax error on one of these lines?

Comment: Nothing stands out here, but make sure you have nothing, including whitespace on the line before or after `EOT;`

Comment: Looks like your `echo` is ok: http://codepad.org/nc1eXe3C

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the tip, that was the error.  You can put that as an answer if you want :P

Comment: @Sam happy to help  I put it in as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have any whitespace before or after the close of a HEREDOC statement.  Be sure there is no space before or after your `EOT;` on this line:

```
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't echo out html.

PHP and HTML should look like this.

```
<? 
  if ($something == true) {
?>
  <p>HTML Goes here</p>
<?
  }
?>
```

Comment: Couldn't disagree more.  The HEREDOC syntax used in the OP is a perfectly valid method of embedding PHP vars into HTML.  Much cleaner than your example.

Comment: I can't stand that method.  If you want to print a var out do <?= $something; ?>

Comment: Your preference is no reason to answer that the OP is doing it wrong.

Comment: Opinion isn't an answer; this doesn't solve any "problem" the OP is asking about.

Comment: The problem turned out to be whitespace.  I don't like the idea of a program not running because of whitespace, if you want to program python, then program python.  This is an alternative piece of code that works and is an answer.

Comment: Using a HEREDOC is a perfectly valid method in PHP. It has nothing to do with preferences; the answer to question was how to properly use a HEREDOC, not how to avoid using a HEREDOC.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your {}'s for your If statement. Also supply an alternate else of else if statement with your HTML in between the statements

Comment: The if statement `}` is closed after the heredoc `EOT;` on the last line.

Comment: You need to put quotes around that string, not process it as a raw string.

Comment: Why are you using HEREDOC anyway. It is completely un-necessary

Comment: i understand the ending bracket is at the end, I am saying out it before the HTML and than add another else/else if statement. It will work the same as the way you have it now.

Comment: @JonahAllibone HEREDOC is a very tidy way of doing what the OP is doing. Several variables embedded in HTML, without function calls mixed in. Sounds like a perfect time for HEREDOC.  And no, HEREDOC should not be surrounded by quotes.